# Passing on multiple rows with radio button values to next page

Tags: jsp

1. I am trying to pass on values with radio buttons from multiple rows in 
   radio_test.jsp code to next page Radio_Sub.jsp, but getting null value.
2. I have tried to pass through array but am not successful.

radio_test.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.* , java.text.* , javax.naming.* ,javax.sql.DataSource ,java.sql.*"  session="true"%>
    <%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Department Contact Details</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    Connection con = null;
    con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/udaipur","root","");
    int user = Integer.parseInt((String)session.getValue("USER"));
    String brn =(String)session.getValue("BRAN");
    int dep = (Integer)session.getValue("DEPT");
    String attn = request.getParameter("atnd");
    int srno=0;

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rset = null;

    String qry = "select a.srno,a.name,c.salde_name,substr(a.cell,3,10),a.email,b.br_name,e.salde_name    from salempl a,albranch b,saldesg c,saldept e where trim(a.brn) =trim(b.branch_code) and a.desig = c.salde_code and a.dept = e.salde_code and e.salde_code = "+dep+" and a.brn = '"+brn+"' and a.classcd=1 order by a.cdr,a.desig";

     rset = stmt.executeQuery(qry);

     %>
     <form method="POST"  name="frm" id="frm" action="Radio_Sub.jsp">
     <table border="1" width="97%"  style="border-collapse: collapse">
     <tr>
     <td colspan="10">
     <p align="center"><b><font size="5">Employee Details of : <%= brn %> for <%=dep %> </font></b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td width="4%" align="center"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><b>S.NO</b></td>
     <td width="8%" align="center"   bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><b>S.R.NO</b></td>
     <td align="center" width="19%"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><b>Name</b></td>
     <td width="12%" align="center"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><b>Designation</b> 
     </td>
     <td width="9%" align="center"   bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><b>Contact No.</b> 
     </td>
     <td align="center" width="6%"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><b>Branch</b></td>
     <td align="center" width="7%"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><b>Dept</b></td>
     <td align="center" width="7%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><b>Present</b></td>
     <td align="center" width="7%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><b>Tour</b></td>
     <td align="center" width="7%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><b>Leave</b></td>

     </tr>
     <%
     int slno = 0;  
     while(rset.next()) 
     {
     ++slno;
     srno=rset.getInt(1);   
     String srnos=Integer.toString(srno);
     %>
     <tr>
     <td width="4%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><%= srnos %></td>
     <td width="8%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><%= srno %></td>
     <td width="19%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >&nbsp;<%= rset.getString(2) </td>
     <td width="12%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><%= rset.getString(3) %> </td>
     <td width="9%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><%= rset.getString(4) %></td>
     <td width="6%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >&nbsp;<%= rset.getString(6) %</td>
     <td width="7%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><%= rset.getString(7) %></td>
     <td width="7%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><p align="center"><input name <%=srnos %>" type="radio" value="P" required/></td>
     <td width="7%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><p align="center"><input name=" <%=srnos %>" type="radio" value="T" required/></td>
     <td width="7%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><p align="center"><input name="<%=srnos %>" type="radio" value="L" required/></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td><input type="hidden" id="thisField" name="inputName" value <%=slno %>"></td>
     </tr>   
     <%
     }

     rset.close();
     stmt.close();
     con.close();
     %>
    </table>
    <p align="center">
    <b>
    <font color="#000080">
    <input type="button" name="reset_form" value="Reset Form" onclick="this.form.reset();" style="color: #0066FF; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight: bold; border-style: groove; border-width: 1px;padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit &gt;&gt;" name="Submit" style="font-variant: small-caps; color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold"></font><font face="Helvetica"><a href="AtndLogin.jsp"><font color="#FF00FF">GO BACK</a></font></b></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Radio_Sub.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=windows1252">
<title>View</title>
</head>

<body>
<% String hidden = request.getParameter("inputName"); 
int j=Integer.parseInt(hidden);
%>

<% String s[] = new String[j];
int k=0;
for (int i=0; i<j; i++){
k++;
s[i] = request.getParameter(Integer.toString(k));
out.println(s[i]);
}
%>          
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting null value in next page, please help, where I am making mistake

Comment: Try to add `request.getParameterMap().forEach( (n,v) -> System.out.println((n + ": " + Arrays.toString(v))));` to Radio_Sub.jsp - you will see (in console, or in `catalina.out` file) what parameters are passed.

Comment: Your radio button have `name="<%=srnos %>"` but your hidden input field have `value=<%=slno %>` is both have same values ? or not ?

Comment: Even after making corrections as suggested, getting NIL values